# Sabre API Response not get Min/Max Stay and Advance Purchase Fields

Tags: sabre, sabredav

I Need results as per GDS system but not for availability . For example when we check fares on GDS with this command ( FQOSLACC15MAY-LH ). We get all the fares without availability restriction. we also get Classes , Fare Basis , Price, Advance Purchase, Min & Max Stay . we Need this fields in my web API response .Please Suggest me Service action code Type.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bargain Finder Max,

here is the link : 
[link](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max)

You will need to request sabre support for activation of BFM.
I hope you are looking for the air availability.

hope this helps